# use test data set after 10 Cross-validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, data-mining, naive-bayes

I applied 10 Cross-validation but I am a bit confused, I am not sure what is a correct way.

1- Should I apply 10 Cross-validation on all dataset, divide it into 10 folds and sum all the 10 matrices like what I am doing on my code.

```
set.seed(100)
library(caTools)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
dataset_folds<-createFolds(wpdc$outcome, k=10) #creat folds 
dataset_fun <- lapply ( dataset_folds, function(x){
  dataset_traing_folds=wpdc[-x,]
  dataset_test_folds=wpdc[x,]
  dataset_test_folds_class<-dataset_test_folds[,1]
  #build the model 
  dataset_model_nb<-naiveBayes(outcome ~ ., data = dataset_traing_folds)
  #test the  model
  dataset_predict_nB<-predict(dataset_model_nb, dataset_test_folds[-1])
  #accuracy
  dataset_table_nB<-table(dataset_test_folds_class,dataset_predict_nB)
  dataset_confusionMatrix_nB<-confusionMatrix(dataset_table_nB, positive ="R")
  return(dataset_confusionMatrix_nB$table)
})
dataset_sum_matrices <-Reduce('+', dataset_fun)#sum 10 matrices
dataset_final_confusionMatrix<-confusionMatrix(dataset_sum_matrices, positive ="R")
```

2- Or should I first divide the dataset into training and testing then apply 10 Cross-validation on training subset just??
but what about a testing subset, how can I use it after 10 Cross-validation?

what is the correct way and why, and Is it necessary to split dataset for cross-validation?? 
thank you